# Tool for monitoring SQL query results needed

Tags: sql, oracle, monitor

I am looking for a tool to monitor results of a periodically run sql query and raise a notification based on the fact that the query returns any results. (any other filters are welcome)

I need to watch a transaction table for errors, and it would be great if my sql query could run in background, refresh itself periodically and show a notification when there are any results.

I need to connect to Oracle DB and I currently use PL/SQL Developer or Oracle SQL Developer.

Free, OS and lightweight solutions preferred :)

UPDATE:

Preferably I would like to not create/modify any database objects. We would like to use this on our clients databases too and not all of them have license to modify the DBs where their Oracle Apps run.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you want the notification?  Email?  SMS?  Message box on your screen?

Comment: http://no0p.github.io/postgresql/2014/10/21/postgresql-monitoring-framework.html plus http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/gallery/index.en.html

Comment: after all these years, if may I ask, how did you finally solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

How about using DBMS_Scheduler to run a stored procedure that queries the table and then uses UTL_Mail to send an email in case of a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put the query in a stored procedure. Have your monitoring / notification code there.

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it works absolutely fine.

-- 1. Create  Program:

```
BEGIN 
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM(
      program_name=>'user.TABLESPACE_MANAGEMENT',
      program_action=>'begin
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
'CREATE TABLE IDLE_TIME_TABLE 
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING
AS 
SELECT DISTINCT 
            SID, 
            OSUSER, 
            USERNAME, 
            STATUS,
            TO_CHAR(LOGON_TIME, ''DDth  DAY  HH24:MI:SS'') LOGON_TIME,
            FLOOR(LAST_CALL_ET/3600)||'':''|| FLOOR(MOD(LAST_CALL_ET,3600)/60)||'':''||MOD(MOD(LAST_CALL_ET,3600),60) IDLE, 
            PROGRAM
FROM V$SESSION
WHERE USERNAME IS NOT NULL
AND STATUS = ''INACTIVE''
ORDER BY IDLE DESC',
      program_type=>'PLSQL_BLOCK',
      number_of_arguments=>0,
      comments=>'TABLESPACE MANAGEMENT CREATES A TABLE CALLED TABLESPACE_MANAGEMNT ON DAILY BASIS',
      enabled=>TRUE);
END;
```

-- 2. Create a schedule program:

```
BEGIN
   sys.dbms_scheduler.create_schedule( 
      repeat_interval =>   
         'FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; BYHOUR=22; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0;',
      start_date => 
         to_timestamp_tz('2011-07-26 US/Eastern', 'YYYY-MM-DD TZR'),
      comments => 
         'Schedule for what ever u want',
      schedule_name => '"user"."TABLESPACE_MANAGEMENT_SCHEDULE"');
END;
```

--3. And finally link both together to create a JOB:

```
BEGIN
   sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job( 
      job_name => '"user"."SPACE"',
      program_name => 'user.TABLESPACE_MANAGEMENT',
      schedule_name => 'user.TABLESPACE_MANAGEMENT_SCHEDULE',
      job_class => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
      comments => 'TABLESPCE_MANAGEMENT',
      auto_drop => FALSE,
      enabled => TRUE);
END;
```

## Now you can use something like utl_mail.send

```
begin
 UTL_MAIL.SEND_ATTACH_VARCHAR2
(
        sender => 'username@whatever.co.uk'
       ,recipients => 'username@whatever.co.uk,username@whatever.co.uk,username@whatever.co.uk,username@whatever.co.uk'
       ,cc => NULL
       ,bcc =>  NULL
       ,subject => 'send_attach_varchar2'
       ,message => 'here is a test of send_attach_varchar2'
       ,mime_type => 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii'
       ,priority => 3
       ,attachment => '<html>
                                        <head>
                                          <title>Test HTML message</title>
                                        </head>
                                        <body>
                                          <p>This is a <b>HTML</b> <i>version</i> of the test message.</p>
                                          <p><img src="http://whatever/images/site_logo.gif" alt="Site Logo" />
                                        </body>
                                      </html>'
       ,att_inline => TRUE
       ,att_mime_type=>'application/html'
       ,att_filename => 'cartesien.html'
   );
```